# How to iterate through unicode characters?

Tags: r, unicode

I am trying to iterate through the cards available through unicode in R:

`cat('\U1F0A1')` for example produces , `cat('\U1F0A2')` produces  and so on...

However, my initial thought of pasting together `'\U1F0A'` with the `paste0` function escapes before being pasted, resulting in:

```
> cat(paste0('\U1F0A','1')) 
Ἂ1
```

Which leaves me with an unusual `A` pasted to a `1`. Does anyone have an idea how I could iterate through the whole suit?

Other attempts that ended in failure:

- Producing all the `"U1F0A1"`,`"U1F0A2"` etc codes and then appending them to `"\"`, but this has issues with backslash being an escape character in R.
- Using the `sprintf` function to insert a value on the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably be better converting to the integer representation of the characters. Find your first point

```
start <- utf8ToInt('\U1F0A1')
```

Then use `intToUtf8` to turn those numbers back into characters

```
intToUtf8(start)
intToUtf8(start + 1)
intToUtf8(start + 2)
# ...etc
```